# Stokes' Theorem and perimeter

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

As a consequence of Stokes' Theorem it seems that the perimeter of a closed curve $C$ can be obtained by choosing $F$ to be the vector field formed by rewriting the unit tangent $T$ of $C$ as a function of position.

Let $T$ be rewritten as a vector field on $\Bbb R^3$:
$$
T =  \langle f(x,y,z), g(x,y,z), h(x,y,z) \rangle.
$$
This vector field obtained from $T$ is defined on the surface patch bounded by $C$ if this vector field for $T$ is defined on a subset of $\Bbb R^3$ containing the surface patch bounded by $C$.

Integrating the curl of this vector field over the surface patch whose boundary is $C$, you get the perimeter (length) of the curve.

For example, suppose the surface is the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and the curve $C$ is the circle of radius $R$ in the $z=R^2$ plane. The unit tangent of $C$ in terms of $x, y$ and $z$ would be $\langle  -y/R , x/R , 0 \rangle$. Integrating the curl of this vector field over the surface patch whose boundary is $C$, you get $2\pi R$.

I've verified it works on a lot of examples.
Analogously, Green's theorem can also be used to find perimeter. Simply find $f$ and $g$ for $T = \langle f(x,y), g(x,y) \rangle $.

Is this a common application of Stokes' Theorem / Green's Theorem? Can anyone attest to ever having heard of it before?

The only reasons I have for believing this actually works are that the math loosely seems to make intuitive sense and that it didn't produce any contradictions when I tested it on examples.

And when I say that the math loosely seems to make intuitive sense, I mean that the length of a curve is equal to the line integral of the unit tangent over the curve.

Comment: But does every smooth curve bound an orientable surface? This is a nontrivial result!

Comment: When you say this is a nontrivial result, do you mean that perhaps it would be worthwhile for someone to write a paper on this? One major purpose behind me making this post was to find out if I'd rediscovered a famous result that already had a name.

Comment: No, this is not a paper a non-expert can write, and it's all in books. The issue I raised is from geometric topology: go read about the *Seifert surface* of a knot (or curve) in space (or more generally). Some algebraic topology will help. The application of Stokes's Theorem is not too feasible; however, Stokes's Theorem (for differential forms) and generalizations of your question lead to a fascinating subject called *calibrated geometries*. You can start by learning differential forms.

Comment: What would happen if I tried to use this to find the perimeter of a closed loop on a non-orientable surface like a Mobius strip? It would fail? The surface integral would return an answer of infinity? Or what's the problem?

Comment: What does the flux of $\vec F$ across a non-orientable surface mean?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, that's a problem. I'm gonna take your recommendations. Thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: One last comment: If you want to think about generalizing Stokes's Theorem to non-orientable manifolds, you might check out T. Frankel's *The Geometry of Physics*. You'll need to be comfortable with differential forms first.

Comment: @TedShifrin every simple closed space curve is a knot. Since every knot is the boundary of some Seifert surface, then doesn't this mean that for any simple closed space curve I can always choose an orientable surface on which to perform my surface integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions of the scalar and vector line integrals are

$$\int_Cf\:ds = \int_a^b f(\mathbf{r}(t))\cdot|\mathbf{r}'(t)|\:dt$$

and

$$\int_C\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{dr} = \int_a^b\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))\cdot\mathbf{r}'(t)\:dt$$

respectively. Notice that when we set $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t)) = \frac{\mathbf{r}'(t)}{|\mathbf{r}'(t)|}$, the vector line integral becomes

$$\int_a^b \frac{\mathbf{r}'(t)}{|\mathbf{r}'(t)|}\cdot\mathbf{r}'(t)\:dt = \int_a^b |\mathbf{r}'(t)|\:dt = \int_C ds \equiv \operatorname{Length}(C)$$

In the special case that $C$ is a differentiable (not piecewise) closed curve, Stokes' theorem applies and you can compute the quantity either as a line integral or a surface integral - which is what you found. Because of the strict quantifiers, this is not commonly useful for curves. But you should still be proud for finding this, as the same intuition is much more broadly applicable to the integrals over surfaces rather than line integrals.

Comment: When you say the same intuition is much more broadly applicable to integrals over surfaces, you're referring to the fact that the divergence theorem can be used to compute surface areas? Or is it even more general than that?

Comment: @SimonM it is more general than that. To put it simply, theorems exist to convert and compute vector integrals but not scalar ones. But the appropriate choice of vector field (taking into account the normal or tangent vector, as it were) can turn a scalar integral into an equivalent vector one, allowing us to use the nice theorems again. Surface area is just the example $f=1$, and you could even use Stokes' theorem instead with a different vector field.